# How to get certain values from session storage? Is it possible?

Tags: session-storage

Let say this is the data which store in session storage and there consists four obj inside{origin: "Johor Bahru", destination: "Ipoh", date: "12/12/2019", pax: "1"}}, can I only retrieve certain obj out from session storage and display it on another page?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get an object by passing the object name to the getItem() function.

```
sessionStorage.getItem('date');
```

And once you've defined something in the sessionStorage, you can access it from every page you want to.

Comment: How did you call it? And beforehand, did you set an item via. setItem() ?

Comment: var route = new Object();

    route.type = document.getElementById('tripSelection').value;
    route.origin = document.getElementById('origin').value;
    route.destination = document.getElementById('destination').value;
    route.date = document.getElementById('departureDate').value;
    route.pax= document.getElementById('paxSel').value;

    sessionStorage.setItem('routeSearch', JSON.stringify(route));

Comment: Did you make sure that the route variable is not empty? Because when you try to call .getItem() on an empty object, then the result will be null.